# Batch file not skipping lines when told to goto

Tags: batch-file, goto

I've used a few gotos here, but whenever I try the file it goes straight to :john before it tries :brutus. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
@echo off

echo ---------------------------
echo System Online
echo ---------------------------
echo.
echo Select Tool:
goto :toolselect
:toolselect
set /p choosetool=Enter a number to select Tool: 
if %choosetool%=='1' goto :hydra
if %choosetool%=='2' goto :john
if %choosetool%=='3' goto :brutus
if %choosetool%=='4' goto :nmap
if %choosetool%=='5' goto :python
if %choosetool%=='' goto :exit

:john
start OpenJohn.bat

:brutus
start C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tools\Brutus.lnk
```

Comment: The fundamental issues are that `==` in an `if` statement matches STRINGS on either side of the `==`, so an unquoted string on the left would never match a quoted string on the right, as solved by foxidrive. The second issue is that batch simply charges on straight through labels; they're not like procedures in other languages, hence since no `if` matchesm, the commands in `:john` are executed, then those in `:brutus` and so on until a GOTO or end-of-file or EXIT or external-batchfile-name is encountered. Note that `goto :eof` (the colon is required) means 'go to end-of-file' (an inbuilt label

Answer (score 1):

Try this block instead - double quotes give you a safe compare and including poison characters.  The lines to catch an invalid input would have let you realise that none of your compares were working.

```
set "choosetool="
set /p "choosetool=Enter a number to select Tool: "
if "%choosetool%"=="1" goto :hydra
if "%choosetool%"=="2" goto :john
if "%choosetool%"=="3" goto :brutus
if "%choosetool%"=="4" goto :nmap
if "%choosetool%"=="5" goto :python
if "%choosetool%"=="" goto :exit
echo invalid input
goto :EOF
```